# Паралакс эффект для фона

Tags: jquery

HTML-код страницы

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #000 url(../images/bg_main.jpg) top center repeat-x;
}
.wrapper {
    background: url(../images/bg_wrapper.png) top center no-repeat;
}
```

Каким образом можно добавить прокрутку бэкграунда в диве `wrapper` ?
jQuery плагины с параллакс эффектом предлагают слишком сложные эффекты, а мне нужна просто прокрутка фона в диве.

Answer (score 2):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwdQZ/)

обновление http://jsfiddle.net/XuKcx/

[обновление 2](http://jsfiddle.net/383NF/) http://jsfiddle.net/383NF/

Comment: Так что-то оно не работает. А прокрутку мне надо добавить просто сверху вниз.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L2HgU/

И в хроме и в фф работает. Прокрутка сверху вниз.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы фон по кругу крутился - уезжал вниз и выезжал сверху? а то сейчас он просто уезжает вниз и все.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XuKcx/

Обновил

Comment: Спасибо, но тоже не то( надо чтобы вниз уезжал, и сверху заново выезжал, и так по кругу(

Comment: Значение координат надо  увеличить и уменьшить. Обновил - 
http://jsfiddle.net/383NF/